# Use of in thickness

Tags: phrase-usage

I need to buy plastic sheet in bulk . And those are sold in two layers but while ordering I need to say thickness of one layer . In this case can I say;

> I need plastic sheet of 2 microns in single layer thickness.

I mean I need sheet in two layer and thickness of one layer is two microns. I used “in one layer thickness “ like “ he is six feet in height”.

Answer (score 1):

When something has multiple dimensions, it is common to use "**in** [dimension]" to specify which dimension you are quoting a measurement for.

For example:

> The wardrobe was 6ft *in height* and 4ft *in width*.

However, you could also say:

> The wardrobe was 6ft high and 4ft wide.

Likewise, with your example you could either say:

> 2 microns thick.

OR

> 2 microns in thickness.

Comment: Is it correct to say '' in single layer thickness.'' ? Because if I say ''in thickness'' the seller may not understood whether single layer is two microns or two layers is two micron.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways. A couple I can think of is  -

> Get me *X (amount)* plastic sheets, 2 microns thick each.

Or...

> Get me *two micron-thick* 10 plastic sheets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ask for a length of the **2 micron thick double layer plastic sheet**.

According to this [English grammar rule](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order), you want to try to put it size, material and type in that order. However, I did put type before material because it was more natural sounding to me.

```
size: 2 micron thick 
material: plastic sheet
type: double-thickness
```

Otherwise it could read: **2 micron thick plastic sheet sold in two layers**